# Xml Parsing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

My xmL:

```
  <Absolventi nume="Ace Timisoara">
    <id>7</id>
    <oras>Timisoara</oras>
  </Absolventi>
```

my code like this:

```
        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
        {

            string nume = node.Attributes["nume"].Value;
            string oras = node.Attributes[0].InnerText;
            int id = int.Parse(node["id"].InnerText);
```

And if i run it i see this: 
https://gyazo.com/e9a213267ee42bd2f671c4325c4b746d

In the property grid, oras should not be the same as nume

```
        string nume = node.Attributes[0].InnerText;
        **string oras = node.Attributes[0].InnerText;**
        int id = int.Parse(node["id"].InnerText);
```

I don't know what to write at node oras so that it shows it's value. I've tried tens of things instead atributes,value etc, but it either doesn't work or just crashes.
I've tried to put value into the brackets like [name] ["name"] [string name] etc, and none of them wroked, or made the app crash..

Thankyou in advance

Comment: Dont show pictures of code. Paste it in and format it

Comment: done, can you give me a tip on my problem?

Comment: Look at your code for `string oras =`. It is not correct, as you noticed. Try figuring out why. Perhaps start trying to answer why actually "nume" and "id" were properly retrieved from the XML. How does the C# code for "nume" and "id" match the XML, and how does the C# code for "oras" _not_ match with the XML. Remember, the C# code you have written is not just a bunch of random words with a few dots and semicolons inbetween. These words appearing blue-ish in your code snippet above have very specific meanings. Read the documentation for each (in VS, move cursor onto them and press F1)...

Comment: You do realize that this question isn't *even remotely* related to Visual Studio, right?

Comment: Why? it's done in VS , c# ...someone even solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check oras like this

```
string doc = @"<Absolventi nume='Ace Timisoara'>
<id>7</id>
<oras>Timisoara</oras>
</Absolventi>";
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(doc);
foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.ChildNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["nume"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(node["id"].InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(node["oras"].InnerText);   
}
```

[Test here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gs0E8C)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, those ( near node really did the trick !!!!